# After df.toPandas().to_csv('mycsv.csv'), data is garbled when reread

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table named result_25. I use this code to successfully export data to csv on my disk.

```
result_25.toPandas().to_csv('mycsv.csv')
```

In order to check whether I save the file correctly, I read my table back in with this code:

```
rr = spark.read.csv('mycsv.csv', inferSchema=True, header=True)
```

I checked the data, it looked like fine.

[rr & result_25 dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YCLF.png)

But when I checked my result_25 and rr with .describe().show(), they show differently(I was expecting they were the same).

[result_25 and rr describe()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Byf3o.png)

And when I grouped by 'prediction', they were even more different.

[rr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpBYe.png)

[result_25](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZUQF.png)

What's wrong here? Anybody can help me? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, [`pandas.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) adds an index to the CSV export (from the docs):

> **index**: *boolean, default True*
>   Write row names (index)

You can export to CSV without the index:

```
result_25.toPandas().to_csv('mycsv.csv', index=False)
```

and you won't see the additional column `_c0` (the column name `_c0` is added by pyspark since pandas does not give any name to the index column).

If you only use spark (and don't need the saved data frame in human-readable format), another way to avoid this is to write/read pyspark data frames in other formats such as JSON or [parquet](http://parquet.apache.org/):

```
# JSON
result_25.write.json('mydataframe.json')
rr = spark.read.json('mydataframe.json')

# parquet
result_25.write.parquet('mydataframe.parquet')
rr = spark.read.parquet('mydataframe.parquet')
```